# OpenWeatherMap API SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, openweathermap

So I am currently working on a personal project to help understand API's and how they work..so I am still a little new to iOS Development. I have already connected to the URL and gotten the data however now I am trying to make the results a little bit more clear cut.

Below is the code for the class (when the button is clicked it prints all this information)

[First part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcyds.png)

[Second part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oUCw.png)

The error I get is Type 'Any' has no subscript members. Any idea as to why? Or how this can be fixed?

Comment: Please search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members

Comment: And please post code as actual code into your question. Do not post pictures of code.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to stack overflow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set their types like this then you can print values.

```
if let main = json["main"] as? [String: Any] {
        let temp = main["temp"] as? Double
        print("temp\(temp!)")

        let temp_max = main["temp_max"] as? Double
        print("temp\(temp_max!)")

        let temp_min = main["temp_min"] as? Double
        print("temp\(temp_min!)")

    }
    let items = json["weather"] as! [AnyObject]
    let main = items[0]["main"] as! String
    print(main)

    let description = items[0]["description"] as! String
    print(description)

    let icon = items[0]["icon"] as! String
    print(icon)

    let name = json["name"] as! String
    print("name\(name)")
```